# Error with templated control with attribute [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)] inside FormView

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, webforms, controltemplate

I've created a Custom Control that has a single ContentTemplate where I've decorated the ITemplate property with the [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)] attribute to make all controls inside directly available without having to use FindControl to access them.

However, if I use my control in a Formviews InsertItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate according to the following...

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="formView">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <my:Control runat="server" ID="myControl">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </my:Control>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <my:Control runat="server" ID="myControl">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </my:Control>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

...I get an error message because the two textboxes (or any other control) inside my ContentTemplate has the same ID:

> "The class XXX already contains a definition for textBox"

I find this very strange since the InsertItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate of the FormView are NOT decorated with the mentioned attribute so all controls inside should get scoped to their template. This is also true for the ID "myControl" in the sample above, that gives no clash...

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? For now I can use different ID:s in the templates but I'd like it to work as is since it's so common that controls inside these FormView templates have the same ID:s.

Comment: My colleague found this bug report that is the same problem only the templates control is an UpdatePanel: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/373771/updatepanel-in-formview-name-conflict-compilation-error

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but when you define `TemplateInstance.Single`, the framework allows direct reference to the control, and therefore ID's have to be unique.  Therefore, you don't need `FindControl()`, but you also need a unique ID to refer  by.  Controls like ListView, where it has an ItemTemplate, use `TemplateInstance.Multiple`.  That's the reason why some template vary by behavior.